# How to intersect two horizontal lists using python?

Tags: python, list, intersection

At the code I'm writing I need to intersect two horizontal list like:

## listA:

```
chr1    aatt
chr8    tagg
chr11   aaaa
chr7    gtag
```

## listB

```
chr8    tagt
chr1    tttt
chr7    gtag
chr11   aaaa
chr9    atat

#This lists are compounded by one str per line, wich it has a "/t" in the middle. 
#Also note that are in different order
```

**How can I get the intersection between this two list?**

## desired result:

```
chr7    gtag
chr11   aaaa
```

I'm also available to generate lists of two string per line, like this:\

## listA:

```
('chr1', 'aatt')
('chr8', 'tagg')
('chr11', 'aaaa')
('chr7', 'gtag')
```

## listB

```
('chr8', 'tagt')
('chr1', 'tttt')
('chr7', 'gtag')
('chr11','aaaa')
('chr9', 'atat')
```

The important matter in this case is that the two columns must be treated as one

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Python [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
listA = (
    ('chr1', 'aatt'),
    ('chr8', 'tagg'),
    ('chr11', 'aaaa'),
    ('chr7', 'gtag'),
)

listB = (
    ('chr8', 'tagt'),
    ('chr1', 'tttt'),
    ('chr7', 'gtag'),
    ('chr11','aaaa'),
    ('chr9', 'atat'),
)

combined = set(listA).intersection(set(listB))
for c, d in combined:
    print c, d
```

You can also use the `&` like this:

```
combined = set(listA) & set(listB)
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert to sets and intersect: `set(a) & set(b)`

Answer (score 2):

Use set intersection.

```
setC = set(listA) & set(listB)
listC = list(setC) # if you really need a list
```

Comment: Did you see the two identical answers above?

Comment: Technically this answer is the most correct of the three, because it returns a list.

Comment: Hmm, not convinced, they asked for an intersection, not specifically a list. Plus a set is clearly the most appropriate return value in the circumstances anyway.

Answer (score 1):

import numpy as np

```
np.intersect_nu(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a performance optimization by not creating 2 sets from lists, which requires hashing all the items in the list, but creating only 1 set and iterating through the second list.  If you know which list is large and which is small that could also help.

```
def intersect(smallList, largeList):
    values = set(smallList)
    intersection = []

    for v in largeList:
        if v in values:
            intersection.append(v)

    return intersection
```